# Does perl's -i with no argument create a backup file on Cygwin?

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have a bug report from a reliable person that on Cygwin and Perl 5.14.2, using perl's `-i` switch with no value creates a *.bak* backup file. It shouldn't according to the documentation in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
If no extension is supplied, no backup is made and the current
file is overwritten.
```

I don't have access to Cygwin at the moment. Does anyone else see this behavior? Can you explain it? Is is something about creating the backup file, which should only be a temporary file, and failing to remove it?

Here's the steps I suggest to recreate it. Remember, this is for Cygwin:

1. Create and change into empty directory
2. Create a text file in that directory. The contents are not important
3. Run `perl -p -i -e 's/perl/Perl/g' filename`
4. Check for a *.bak* file when you are done

Save the answers for an explanation of what might be happening if you find that backup file. Upvoting a prior comment for "Yes I see that" or "No, can't reproduce it" can be an informal poll.

Comment: The cygwin build of Perl does create a `.bak` for me. In fact, `$^I` contains `.bak`. Cygwin's emulation of unix apparently does not go as far as adding support for anonymous files.

Comment: May I suggest to add the tag "in-place" and to replace the tag cygwin with windows because I have the same issue with an MSYS port of perl, in a windows git bash (uname says MINGW64_NT-10.0) and I didn't find this question quickly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[perldoc perlcygwin](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcygwin.html#*-Miscellaneous) sayeth (edited for clarity):

> Because of Windows-ish restrictions, inplace editing of files with `perl -i`
>   must create a
>   backup of each file being edited. Therefore Perl adds the suffix `.bak` automatically — as
>   though invoked with `perl -i.bak`— if
>   you use `perl -i` with no explicit backup extension.

Arguably this information should be in [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) also.

Comment: "Yes, I see that." on many versions of Cygwin from 5.8.4 to 5.15.6

Comment: Aw, don't I feel stupid. I never even thought to look for that file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For example:

```
    # show we're in cygwin
% uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 xzodin 1.7.15(0.260/5/3) 2012-05-09 10:25 i686 Cygwin
    # show that directory is empty
% ls
    # create a file
% touch foo
    # invoke 'perl -pi' (but do nothing)
% perl -pi -e "" foo
    # show that a backup file with extension '.bak' is created.
% ls
foo  foo.bak
```